# Sytax error - unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Can anyone spot why I'm getting an error? It seems to be the last  tag but removing it is not the solution.

Ask Question

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EIio.png)
  
    
      
          
            ×
            
            Ask a Question

```
  <!-- <%= form_for :question, url: '/questions', html: {class: 'form-horizontal'} do%>  -->
      <div class="modal-body">  
        <form class="form-horizontal">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" required>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputQuestion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Question</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea class="formControl" class="form-control" id="inputQuestion" placeholder="What would you like to know?" required></textarea>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              </div>
        </form>

      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your rails `form_for` tag has no `end` tag? you have it in an html comment however erb will be processed on the server first remove this code `<!-- <%= form_for :question, url: '/questions', html: {class: 'form-horizontal'} do%>  -->`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're opening a Ruby block here:

```eruby
<!-- <%= form_for :question, url: '/questions', html: {class: 'form-horizontal'} do %>  -->
```

...but you never close it.

Keep in mind that ERB doesn't know anything about HTML, so putting ERB code inside HTML comments doesn't stop it from running. If you do `<!-- <%= "foo" %> -->` it'll render `<!-- foo -->`.

If you want to comment out ERb code, replace the opening tag with `<%#`:

```eruby
<%#= form_for :question, url: '/questions', html: {class: 'form-horizontal'} do %>
```

If your block has a corresponding `<% end %>`, don't forget to comment that out as well:

```eruby
<%#= form_for :question, url: '/questions', html: {class: 'form-horizontal'} do %>
  ...
<%# end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are commenting out the form_for the html way, but that does not actually comment it out. Your page is looking for a <% end %> and doesn't find it.

If you want the form_for commented out you need to do it like so:

```
<% #form_for :question, url: '/questions', html: {class: 'form-horizontal'} do%>
```